# Apply na.locf to multiple datasets

Tags: r, loops

I have multiple datasets (Eg: data01, data02..). In all these datasets, I want to apply na.locf to var1, and create a new variable 'var2' from the locf applied 'var1'. I tried using the following code:

L=list(data01,data02)
for (i in L){i$var2 <- na.locf(i$var1)}

However, when I try to read the locf column using code:

head(data01$var2)

The result given is NULL.

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag and in particular provide *complete* information including all inputs and library statements so that it is reproducible.  Also indent each code line by 4 spaces in which case SO will format it for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

- in the question i is a copy of each data frame so L is not changed.  Index into L to ensure that it is the data frame in L that is changed.
- use na.locf0 or equivalently na.locf(..., na.rm = FALSE) to ensure that the output is the same length as the input
- the data01 and data02 in L are copies of data01 and data02 and modifying one does not modify the other. That is why you get NULL.

Using the built-in BOD data frame to construct sample input:

```
library(zoo)

# construct sample input
BOD1 <- BOD2 <- BOD
BOD1$Time[c(1, 3)] <- BOD2$Time[c(3, 5)] <- NA
L <- list(BOD1, BOD2)

for(i in seq_along(L)) L[[i]]$Time2 <- na.locf0(L[[i]]$Time)
```

giving:

```
str(L)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':       6 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Time  : num [1:6] NA 2 NA 4 5 7
  ..$ demand: num [1:6] 8.3 10.3 19 16 15.6 19.8
  ..$ Time2 : num [1:6] NA 2 2 4 5 7
  ..- attr(*, "reference")= chr "A1.4, p. 270"
 $ :'data.frame':       6 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Time  : num [1:6] 1 2 NA 4 NA 7
  ..$ demand: num [1:6] 8.3 10.3 19 16 15.6 19.8
  ..$ Time2 : num [1:6] 1 2 2 4 4 7
  ..- attr(*, "reference")= chr "A1.4, p. 270"
```

Any of these would also work and instead of modifying L produce a new list:

```
L2 <- lapply(L, function(x) { x$Time2 <- na.locf0(x$Time); x })

L3 <- lapply(L, transform, Time2 = na.locf0(Time))
```

If your aim is to modify BOD1 and BOD2 as opposed to creating a list with the modified BOD1 and BOD2 then the following would do that (although it is usually better to organize objects in a list if you intend to iterate over them) rather than leave them loose in the global environment.

```
nms <- c("BOD1", "BOD2")
for(nm in nms) assign(nm, transform(get(nm), Time2 = na.locf0(Time)))
```

or

```
nms <- c("BOD1", "BOD2")
for(nm in nms) .GlobalEnv[[nm]]$Time2 <- na.locf0(.GlobalEnv[[nm]]$Time2)
```

or other variations.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! The first solution still gives NULL as result. If I use the second solution (L2), how would I access BOD1,BOD2 in my next coding steps? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: L[[1]] and L[[2]] are the two components of L. If you are trying to access the Time2 column of the first component of the list then it would be L[[1]]$Time2. I have added a third point at the top discussing why you get NULL.